# Trying to achieve a certain animation

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to create this animation in my website using clip path transition but i've been struggling to achieve it. Any help would be appreciated.

here is the animation:
https://dribbble.com/shots/16533457-Vinyl-Web-Design-for-Vinyl-Store

Here is my code so far:
globals.css

```
.billboard-transition {
  transition: background-color 1s circle;
  animation: circle 1s;
}

@keyframes circle {
  0% {
    clip-path: circle(75%);
  }
  50% {
    clip-path: circle(25%);
  }
  100% {
    clip-path: circle(75%);
  }
}
```

HeroSection.tsx

```
const HeroSection = ({ order, genres, billboards }: HeroSectionProps) => {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [isTransition, setIsTransition] = useState(false);

  const previousSlide = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((currentIndex - 1 + billboards.length) % billboards.length);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsTransition(true);
    }, 50);
    setIsTransition(false);
  };

  const nextSlide = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((currentIndex + 1) % billboards.length);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsTransition(true);
    }, 50);
    setIsTransition(false);
  };

  const currentBillboard = billboards[currentIndex];

  const previousIndex =
    (currentIndex - 1 + billboards.length) % billboards.length;
  const nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % billboards.length;

  const modalColor = color(currentBillboard.color)
    .saturate(-0.4)
    .darken(0.4)
    .hex();

  const textColor = "text-white";

  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor: `${currentBillboard.color}`,
        }}
        className={`${textColor} auto h-screen max-w-screen justify-between current-billboard ${
          isTransition ? "billboard-transition" : ""
        }`}
      >

     //Other components

   </div>
  </>
  );
};
export default HeroSection;
```